# Vertical centering of figure

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I understand from other posts that a single float should automatically be centered vertically on the page; however, this does not seem to be the case in my code. Why?

I use the book class.

Both examples below result in the figures being placed on the top of the page.

```
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[ht]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Picture}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.0,clip]{pic1.eps}
\caption{pic1}
\label{pic1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[H]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Picture}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,clip]{pic2.eps}
\caption{pic2}
\label{pic2}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

Comment: If you use `\begin{figure}[p]` or `\begin{figure}[H]` it does work (unless you have specific stuff that interfers with them). Note that the latter requires the `float` package.

Comment: @karlkoeller not `H` unless your normal page text is vertically centred which isn't usually the case

Comment: It seems that    \begin{figure}[p] did the trick.  However,    \begin{figure}[H] does not work even with the    float package. I have noticed that the large figures got centered when they happend to be alone on the page, but when I added a    \clearpage after each figure this changed.

Comment: @David, sure, you're right. But strangely it works if you don't load `float` ?!? Any thought? Is it because `H` is not recognised and `p` is used as default?

Comment: @karlkoeller well htpb is default and presumably it ended up being p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved by using

```
\begin{figure}[p]
```

Comment: did not work with me, the image just dissappared \begin{figure}[p]\includegraphics{./img.png}\end{figure}, why?

Comment: [p] moves floats to a special page for floats only, so the image probably moved to its own page.